# How to get the difference in days between two dates using shell commands?

Tags: shell, date

Using shell commands or the `date` command, how do I get the number of days between two dates?
e.g., `2010-06-01 - 2010-05-15`

Comment: `python -c'from datetime import date; print(date(2010, 6, 1) - date(2010, 5, 15)).days'`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using only date and shell arithmetics:

```
echo $((($(date -d "2010-06-01" "+%s") - $(date -d "2010-05-15" "+%s")) / 86400))
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `$(())` twice. Just use a set of grouping parentheses: `echo $(( ( $(date -d "2010-06-01" "+%s") - $(date -d "2010-05-15" "+%s") ) / 86400))` (optional spaces added for emphasis and readability)

Comment: Note that `%s` is specific to GNU date, so it might not be available on non-Linux systems. The [comp.unix.shell FAQ](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq.html#6) has a long discussion on date calculations (basically, it's hard unless you have GNU date).

Comment: In fact there's a bigger problem: it sometimes fails in the spring… [My answer explains why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385003/shell-script-to-get-difference-in-two-dates/3391111#3391111)

Answer (score 14):

There's a solution that *almost* works: use the `%s` date format of GNU date, which prints the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00. These can be subtracted to find the time difference between two dates.

```
echo $(( ($(date -d 2010-06-01 +%s) - $(date -d 2010-05-15 +%s)) / 86400))
```

But the following displays 0 in some locations:

```
echo $((($(date -d 2010-03-29 +%s) - $(date -d 2010-03-28 +%s)) / 86400))
```

Because of daylight savings time, there are only 23 hours between those times. You need to add at least one hour (and at most 23) to be safe.

```
echo $((($(date -d 2010-03-29 +%s) - $(date -d 2010-03-28 +%s) + 43200) / 86400))
```

Or you can tell `date` to work in a timezone without DST.

```
echo $((($(date -u -d 2010-03-29 +%s) - $(date -u -d 2010-03-28 +%s)) / 86400))
```

(POSIX says to call the reference timezone is UTC, but it also says not to count leap seconds, so the number of seconds in a day is always exactly 86400 in a GMT+xx timezone.)

Comment: Your third example actually yields `82800` because you misgrouped the expression and are actually adding `0` due to the higher precedence of `/`, can you fix the typo?

Answer (score 6):

OSX `date` is different than GNU `date`. Got it working like this in OSX. This is **not portable** solution.

```
start_date=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2010-05-15" "+%s")
end_date=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2010-06-01" "+%s")

echo $(( ($end_date - $start_date) / (60 * 60 * 24) ))
```

Idea is still same as in the other answers. Convert dates to epoch time, subtract and convert result to days.

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
             d1=`date +%s -d $1`
             d2=`date +%s -d $2`
            ((diff_sec=d2-d1))
         echo - | awk -v SECS=$diff_sec '{printf "Number of days : %d",SECS/(60*60*24)}'
```

thanks..

Comment: If you're going to use `(())` you might as well also use `$()` instead of backticks. Also, there's no need to pipe something into `awk`, just use `awk ... 'BEGIN {printf ...}'`. And you don't really need to use `awk` if it's just integer math: `echo "Number of days: $(( ( d2 - d1 ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ))"`

Answer (score 0):

Gnu date knows %j to display the day in year:

```
echo $(($(date -d 2010-06-01 +%j) - $(date -d 2010-05-15 +%j)))
```

crossing year-boundaries will give wrong results, but since you gave fixed dates ...