# Date manipulation in AIX shell script

Tags: shell, unix, aix

Sorry if its repetition of any old post. If so, kindly redirect.

Iam working on a shell script in AIX where we get a date from a file/command line.
Now, i have to compare the current date with the input date and see the number of days difference.

I tried to google for its solution, but everywhere ended up with no proper solution.

Here i cant set the "date" variable, as iam not a root user.

Any inputs would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

For anything slightly more complicated I'd suggest using datecalc (you can find a version at http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/4870-days-elapsed-between-2-dates.html#post16559). It's implementable in most UNIX dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu date has the --date option which satisfies your requirement.
But since that's not available by default in AIX it wont help you.
 So you have to write your own code using awk/perl to achieve it.
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163257/using-awk-to-check-between-two-dates) in stackoverflow which gives some idea about date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(($(($(date -d "2010-06-01" "+%s") - $(date -d "2010-05-15" "+%s"))) / 86400))
```

Source : [Shell script to get difference in two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385003/395703)

Comment: Only with GNU date, not on AIX.